# IPublicClientApplication.GetAccountsAsync() returns only empty array

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

IPublicClientApplication.GetAccountsAsync() returns only empty array in xamarin forms app.
so it ask to login every time app launches.

-- Expected behavior
After first login, I think _pca.GetAccountsAsync() should return accounts list and be able to refresh token

-- Actual behavior
always _pca.GetAccountsAsync() returns empty array so, can't refresh token
So it ask to login every time app launches.

```
    public async Task<UserContext> SingInWithoutInteractively()
    {
        UserContext newContext;
        try
        {
            // acquire token silent
            newContext = await AcquireToken();

        } catch
        {
            newContext = null;
        }

        return newContext;
    }

    public async Task<UserContext> SignInAsync()
    {
        UserContext newContext;
        try
        {
            // acquire token silent
            newContext = await AcquireToken();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            // acquire token interactive
            newContext = await SignInInteractively();
        }
        return newContext;
    }

    private async Task<UserContext> AcquireToken()
    {
        IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await _pca.GetAccountsAsync();
        AuthenticationResult authResult = await _pca.AcquireTokenSilent(B2CConstants.Scopes, GetAccountByPolicy(accounts, B2CConstants.PolicySignUpSignIn))
           .WithB2CAuthority(B2CConstants.AuthoritySignInSignUp)
           .ExecuteAsync();
        
        var newContext = UpdateUserInfo(authResult);
        return newContext;
    }
    private async Task<UserContext> SignInInteractively()
    {
        IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await _pca.GetAccountsAsync();

        AuthenticationResult authResult = await _pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(B2CConstants.Scopes)
            .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
            .WithAccount(GetAccountByPolicy(accounts, B2CConstants.PolicySignUpSignIn))
            .ExecuteAsync();
        
        var newContext = UpdateUserInfo(authResult);            
        return newContext;
    }
    private IAccount GetAccountByPolicy(IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts, string policy)
    {
        foreach (var account in accounts)
        {
            string userIdentifier = account.HomeAccountId.ObjectId.Split('.')[0];
            if (userIdentifier.EndsWith(policy.ToLower())) return account;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, here is a dicsussion in [Github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/137), you could have a check whehter it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
[MsalUiRequiredExceptionFilter（Scopes = new [] {Constants.ScopeUserRead}）]
```

please see:[here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/137).

Answer (score 0):

After adding openid scope, this problem is resolved

Comment: Could you please share how you did that ?